# Cordova add custom framework - Link errors

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

I'm trying to add a custom framework to the plugin I'm building.
The issue is that the header file has dependencies to my framework folder

If I do it like this, I have an issue because it can't find the framework at runtime.

```
<source-file src="src/ios/my.framework" 
framework="true"/>
```

If I do it like this I have linker errors

```
<framework src="src/ios/my.framework" custom="true" 
embed="true" />
```

I could fix it manually on xCode, but I require when adding the plugin, to be automatically working. any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you include both the header-file and framework lines? I have plugins that include native frameworks and reference them from the plugin implementation.

```
    <header-file src="src/ios/SomePlugin.h" target-dir="SomePlugin" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/SomePlugin.m" target-dir="SomePlugin" />

    <framework src="SomeSDK" type="podspec" spec="~> 1.9.9"/>
```

Before CocoaPods I'd do something like

```
    <framework src="lib/SomeSDK.framework" custom="true"/>
```